# QML text element data type/rendering issue, disappearing letters

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qt5

Using Qt 5 beta2 -- I am trying to set a QML text element text property, using a `QVector  <QVariant>` loaded out of a db query.

This Works --

```
textobject = rootitem->findChild<QObject*>("titletext");
textobject->setProperty("text", G_names[1]);
```

-- for a while, and then certain letters stop being visible. So it's getting the data passed in but
then stops rendering. If I do this --

```
textobject = rootitem->findChild<QObject*>("titletext");
textobject->setProperty("text", "const_char_string");
```

-- it works fine, I can keep loading as many characters as I need. I tried converting from a QVector into a const char* by using

```
 QByteArray ba = the_string.toLatin1();
 const char *c_str = ba.data();  

 textobject->setProperty("text", c_str);
```

-- but it wont work. Same thing, stops showing certain letters in a seemingly random manner.

How do I get a value out of a QVector into a type that the QML text renderer
accepts like it does a "string" ? Is it a bug? I can't find any reference
to a problem like this and I've been searching for days. Any help would be greatly 
appreciated.

Comment: Try something like `QString s1 = G_names[1].toString();` and inspect the string contents first (may be you are getting nulls or garbage?).

There's also a way to check if the conversion is ok: check `QVariant::type()` and `QVariant::canConvert(Type t) const` in the docs (may be you're not getting strings at all, or (!!!) they're not in correct encoding -- I bet this is the most probable case, see your Qt SQL plugin's docs on that).

Comment: Thanks For the help, really appreciate it. The string from the database is there, not null or anything. The debugger shows the QVector with "string" values. It's utf8 from the db into a QVector of valid QStrings and everything shows up drawn on the screen for a few function calls, and then it chokes on certain random letters. I rebuilt the mysql plugin statically, didn't change anything. QVariant::canConvert(); returns true on G_names[1]. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'd try to 1) (manually) pass just the same strings as those that are read from the database (may be the text itself breaks QML items) 2) suspecting that there's something slightly wrong with string encodings (invisible symbols, ignored by debugger and qDebug output, etc), gradually string-by-string replacing the input from 1) with actaually read data until something breaks (that will be the time to look at a particular string, possibly examinating the memory char-by-char or saving to a file and using an external tool -- i.e. a hex (or encoding-aware) viewer). Don't give up! ;)

Comment: So, did you pin down that bug?

Comment: No. Made sure all the encoding coming from the db, all source files, is utf-8. Everything from the db will display correctly if it is the first time through the function, so I'm relatively sure it's not an encoding issue. Saw a reference to an issue on the QT bug tracker about the QML font rendering stopping after a large number of text elements being created so I think that's most likely the problem. I'm screwed if they don't fix it In the official Qt5 release. As in the show is stopped. Thanks for your help and concern, if you have any other ideas as to what it might be I'm all ears.

Comment: One thing you could do is create a dumbed-down BUG-reproducing version of the app (w/o a database, essentially just a long loop passing values to a QML Text item), make sure it reliably breaks after (about) 100, or 1000 (or more) proerty resets, vote for the bug in JIRA, start watching it, add a request / comment, and have a beer :) 
You could also try #qt-qml and #qt IRC chat rooms on freenode, the guys there may know / think of workarounds.

Comment: It's doing it just from text elements loaded from qml files now. I'm going with it being a Beta version bug and am going to re-address the issue after the official release. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, and good luck fighting with that filthy Item-s :)